# Adding CSS file for IE

Tags: css

`<!--[if IE]>` is not working.  Is this possible to do in SharePoint?
I have tried SharePoint:CssRegistration but had no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internet Explorer up to and including version 9 does support conditional comments like those:

```
<!--[if IE]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Style Library/custom.css"></link><![endif]-->

<SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="/Style Library/custom.css" ConditionalExpression="IE" runat="server"></SharePoint:CssRegistration>
```

However, Internet Explorer 10 and above has dropped support for those conditional comments hence you are not able to target CSS in an easy way to IE 10+.

**Update**

If you need to target IE 10+ don't use JavaScript to sniff the Web browser user agent as the accepted answer of the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900311/how-do-i-target-only-internet-explorer-10-for-certain-situations-like-internet-e) @Tiago provided does.

Instead either use pure CSS like this:

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none)
{
   /* IE10 and IE11-specific styles go here */
}
@media screen and (min-width:0\0)
{
    /* IE9 and IE10 rule sets go here */
}
```

or use JavaScript feature detection, like checking for the existence of `document.documentMode` and `document.documentMode===10` or `document.documentMode===11` like this:

```
if (document.documentMode != undefined && document.documentMode===10)
{
  // This is IE 10
}
if (document.documentMode != undefined && document.documentMode===11)
{
  // This is IE 11
}
```

Having said that, it all depends heavily on the SharePoint version you are using (SP2010 puts IE 9/10/11+ into 8-mode, SP2013 puts IE 11+ into 10-mode) and if you are running with the out-of-the-box masterpages (e.g. seattle.master on SP2013) or if you have customized your masterpage and modified the `X-UA-Compatible` meta tag (which I personally recommend against heavily as it might break standard SP functionality).

Answer (score 0):

cssregistration has an attribute `ConditionalExpression`

you can set it to `IE` instead of using the IF comments

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(VS.85).aspx

for IE10+ you can try one of the many approaches found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900311/how-do-i-target-only-internet-explorer-10-for-certain-situations-like-internet-e)